# How would i filter an array of products with multiple conditions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, angular, filter

I am making an e-commerce site and i added a checkbox feature on the side showing all the brands and i want to filter the product array (over 900 products)

```
         let products = [
            {name: 'computer', category: 'tech'},
            {name: 'soap', category: 'hygiene'},
            {name: 'bbq', category: 'outdoors'}
        ]
        let categoriesToFilterBy = ['tech', 'outdoors'];

        let newProductsArr = products.filter(product => {
            // ??
        })
```

Answer (score 4):

You can optimize the other solutions if your `categoriesToFilterBy`  can be big. `Array#filter`, `Array#indexOf` and `Array#includes` are all 'hidden' Loops. This will give u a runtime complexity of `n^m` which is bad if your `n` (number of products) can be 900 and your `m` (number of filters) can also be big. Instead create a `Set` from `categoriesToFilterBy`  to get a linear runtime complexity of `n` because the `Set#has` check is done in constant time, no matter how many elements your set have.

```
let categoriesToFilterBy = ['tech', 'outdoors'];
let filterSet = new Set(categoriesToFilterBy);
let filteredProducts = products.filter(product => filterSet.has(product.category))
```

or if you have to support `ES5`

```
let categoriesToFilterBy = ['tech', 'outdoors'];
let filterSet = {};
categoriesToFilterBy.forEach(filter => filterSet[filter] = true);
let filteredProducts = products.filter(product => filterSet[product.category])
```

or if every product has many categories

```
let products = [
   { name: 'computer', categories: ['tech'] },
   { name: 'soap', categories: ['hygiene', 'tech'] }, 
   { name: 'bbq', categories: ['outdoors'] }
];

let categoriesToFilterBy = ['tech', 'outdoors'];
let filterSet = new Set(categoriesToFilterBy);
let filteredProducts = products.filter(product => 
   product.categories.some(category => filterSet.has(category))
);
```

Comment: Does `.has()` compare all elements in `category` with the elements in `filterSet`? Then wouldn't the time complexity still n^m?

Comment: It does compare to all elements, but this comparison is done in constant O(1) time. It like looking up a key inside an javascript object. Thats why values inside a set are unique.

Answer (score 0):

```
        let categoriesToFilterBy = ['tech', 'outdoors'];

        let newProductsArr = products.filter(product => {
            for(let i = 0; i < categoriesToFilterBy.length; i++){
                if(categoriesToFilterBy[i] === product.category) return true;
            }
        })
```

You would just add a for loop inside the filter function, returning true if any of the conditions match.

Comment: better to use indexOf or includes etc. rather than using loop

Comment: @pc_coder Unfortunately `indexOf` and `includes` also use a loop interally and have linear runtime :(

Comment: @Caleb Justice Your if statement has a mistake. It should be `if(categoriesToFilterBy[i] === product.category)`